# How to update or remove pre-installed Swiftkey from Alcatel One Touch 2 Mini S

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, swiftkey

My girlfriend's new smartphone comes with preinstalled Swiftkey 4.1.
She installed 5.0 (so she can download her dictionary from cloud), but the old version still exists. How can we uninstall, or update it?

The phone has Android 4.3. She doesn't want to root it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only uninstall with root.

If she doesn't want to root it, you can uninstall all the updates, and disable in the options to dont show in the keyboard selector.

More Info: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2614022